# Random Restarts [Not Heat Related]

Tags: windows-7, crash, reboot

As recently as in the last three days, my computer, during very or what seemed very random times, would just restart. The fans wouldn't even go to a halt and the lights wouldn't turn off. Normally when I restart my computer those all turn off, but these restarts have happened during the middle of a game, watching a YouTube video, and starting up a video game. Automatic restarts are off. I've checked Event Viewer for anything strange and it was just a message stating the time of the unexpected shutdowns. I've still watched YouTube videos with no problems in between restarts and the same for games. My temperatures are normally a basic 37°C while idling and 45-47 in a game. My PSU is not that old, being 1-1½ years old.

Hardware specifications:

- [CPU] - AMD Phenom II x6 1045
- [GPU] - GeForce GTX 650 EVGA
- [Motherboard] - ASUS M5A78L-M LX Plus
- [PSU] - Corsair CX 600W
- [Ram] -    8 GB (Have no idea who made it since this is my oldest part)
- [Hard drive] - SEAGATE Barracuda 1TB

---

Event Viewer log:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        EventLog
Date:          5/2/2015 5:02:44 PM
Event ID:      6008
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A 
Computer:      Bill-PC
Description:   The previous system shutdown at 5:00:33 PM on 5/‎2/‎2015 was unexpected. Event
```

XML view:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="EventLog" 
    <EventID Qualifiers="32768">6008</EventID>
    <Level>Level2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    SystemTime="2015-05-02T21:02:44.000000000Z" 
    <EventRecordID>411973</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>Bill-PC</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>5:00:33 PM</Data>
      <Data>‎5/‎2/‎2015</Data>
      <Data>
      </Data>
      <Data>
      </Data>
      <Data>23649</Data>
      <Data>
      </Data>
      <Data>
      </Data>
    <Binary>DF07050006000200110000002100C002DF07050006000200150000002100C002600900003C000000010000006009000000000000B00400000100000000000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: If its restarting its generating a log of some sort.  We need that information

Comment: 1) Make sure thermal paste is there. 2) Check GPU temperature, maybe it exceeds allowed limits. 3) Have you just updated GPU drivers? Roll back or (preferably) reinstall previous version of drivers. They are known to cause such random crashes.

Comment: My thermal paste is ok, GPU temperatures I know are in check but I'll try rerolling my video drivers back to an older version that I know was fully functional.

Comment: @Bill: I edited your question, trying to clean up the XML, among other things.  I suspect that the XML is still wrong; please check it.

Comment: @G-Man It looks absolutely the same as the Event Viewer log.

Comment: Even the last 12 lines, with the `<Data>` and `</Data>` with nothing between them?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what it states.

Comment: You should look at each event log before the time the PC crashed to see what the last events were before the system stopped writing to the logs. If no events help explain what caused the reboot, I would do a chkdsk if that is clean start removing/replacing components to see if the problem persists.

Comment: Could be a GPU problem given that crashes seem to occur when you are watching videos or playing games, unless that is all you do on your PC ;-) Alternatively could be a failing PSU, especially that it may not be providing enough power reliably for GPU. I suggest you make sure you are using latest stable driver for your GPU, then if that fails try changing PSU.

Comment: Considering I've used the PSU with this GPU for over a year and half and haven't had the problems until now, I think it's not the GPU not getting enough power. However I cleaned all the dust out last night replugged everything and I'll see today if I get another reboot.